# How can I compute the value of the following Legendre symbol?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The symbol computed for Legendre is (59/619)

The first step I understand is to make it - (619/59) because both are congruent to -1( mod 4). Afterwords I understand it turns into -(29/59) because it is the remainder between 619, 59. I don't understand how in the next step it would turn into -(1/29) afterwards because I don't understand which rule was applied. And afterwords, of course, it becomes -1 which I don't know which rule.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you tried applying the rules yourself?  You seem to be making the assumption that only one rule was applied from (29/59) to (1/29), but it's easy to verify that you get there after two applications of rules that you already understand.

Comment: Sorry. I understand that in the end it becomes -1. I added detail

Comment: Also,  there probably are some preceding steps. I followed according to the internet calculation. I was of course not completely certain about which rule goes where I do know some rules however

Comment: What @ErickWong is trying to say is that by using the reciprocal rule and remainder rule you have already used you will get your missing steps...

Comment: Oh, wow. You are right Thanks

Comment: I figured out that it becomes (59/29) which then is (1/29) however it seems that there should be a negative which I'm not sure because both num and denom are not -1(mod 4)

Comment: Oh, right I preserve previous negative thank you

Comment: Actually I'm confused about the last step. When it's -(1/29) I do (-1)^ ((p-1)/2 )and it becomes (-1)^14 which is +1, but it seems that the answer is - 1. Not sure how the answer was arrived. Thanks